# Performance testing of Android app

Tags: android, testing, httprequest

I have developed an app which make connection to MySQL database and display some information from there. Is there a way to test performance of app like simulation of different amount of users request. 
500 HTTP requests
1000, 1500 request.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try with [JMeter](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/jmeter_proxy_step_by_step.pdf). It's free tool. I've been using it to simulate http request to pages. Hope its help.

Answer (score 2):

Yes it is possible ... Performance Testing a Mobile Application is different from server or other applications.

Simulating the load can be done by pushing dummy records to SQLite Table and doing your testing. However, Since you mentioned that

```
app which make connection to MySQL database and display some information from there
```

I would like to suggest you to look for the following.

1. Analyze the data parsing logic and how the data is rendered on device.
2. Data Retrieval Thread should be separate from Main Thread.
3. Data Parsing should occur in parts. User should not wait for all 500 records to be parsed before rendering on screen. To do this, in the code, based on device screen size data retrieval count should be managed.
4. What are the views used to render the data on screen ? If list View, see how the data is getting recycled.
5. In SQLite, if they are storing images, see if BLOB datatype is used.
6. Check the frequency of database interaction. This would impact the application performance highly.

Hope this helps.